# Grouping neighboring points of same y from array of points

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates

If you had an array of points such as ([[y, x]])

```
var arr = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5]]
```

What's the best or accepted method of grouping the neighboring points with the same Y? So that you could end up with a result such as ([[y, x1, x2]])

```
var result = [[0, 0, 2], [2, 3, 5]]
```

Here's my try:

```
function generateSelectionDimensions (els) {
    var groups = [];
    var cur = null;

    //may not be in order so we sort
    els = els.sort(function(a,b) {
        if( a[0] == b[0]) return a[1] - b[1];
        return a[0] - b[0];
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        var y = els[i][0];
        var x = els[i][1];

        if(!!els[i - 1]) {
            var prevY = els[i - 1][0];
            var prevX = els[i - 1][1];
        }

        var neighbor = !!els[i - 1] ? prevY === y 
            && (prevX - x === 1 || x - prevX === 1) : false;

        if(!neighbor) {
            if(cur) groups.push(cur);
            cur = {y: y, x1: x, x2: 0};
        } else {
            cur.x2 = x;
            if(els.length - 1 === i) groups.push(cur);
        }
    }

    return groups;
}
```

Comment: In the resulting array I need [y, x1, x2]. I only need x1 and x2, where x1 is the x of the first point of the 'group' and x2 is the last point of the 'group'. Group meaning all the points that are directly adjacent on the x-axis and on the same y-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps:

- sort by the first coordinate, then by the second
- for each element in the (sorted) array: if it fits into the last range, add it to the range, otherwise create a new range.

```js
var arr = [[2, 6], [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [2, 5], [0, 8], [0, 9]]
var res = [];

arr.sort(function (a, b) {

    return a[0] - b[0] || a[1] - b[1];

}).forEach(function (a) {

    if (res.length > 0) {
        var last = res[res.length - 1];

        if (last[0] === a[0] && last[2] === a[1] - 1) {
            last[2]++;
            return;
        }
    }

    res.push([a[0], a[1], a[1]]);

});

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very helpful. I guess I was over-complicating it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use an algorithm similar to this, it would be much simpler than your attempt:

1. generate an array of all the unique `y values` and another array `sizes`, which is how many times the appears
2. Now you know how many groups you will have (the number of unique `y values`) and how big they will be (values in `sizes`)
3. Loop though the initial points, and add the `x value` to the associated group to the `y value`